# Home network traffic monitoring and routing solutions?

Tags: networking, routing, port-forwarding

Here is a data scientist building a home network and looking for opinions of experienced people in this area. I have a following components I wanna connect together in a correct way:

- Mini-PC (linux server)
- Bunch of smart home devices
- Modem/router

Mini-PC will be used as web server, ftp server, DNS server, HTPC and [Home Assistant](https://home-assistant.io) hub for smart home devices. The starting point would be to setup an ssh server in order to be able to access my server remotely. First problem I came across is that my modem/router does not support port forwarding nor UPnP (which is not the desired solution as it's dangerous?) making it inaccessible from outside.

**i)**

Regarding port forwarding I came across this piece of software called [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), which enables me to do exactly the thing I want. My only concern is that it uses their external DNS servers in order to bypass NAT and resolve the routing and if this could lead to security issues? I would rather have everything locally, if possible. I was also reading about the port forwarding using iptables:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 10.0.0.132 --dport 29418 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.133:29418
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -s 127.0.0.1 -j MASQUERADE
```

I am just not sure how the traffic is handled? Does my mini-PC need to be ethernet connected to modem in order to work or do these packages get broadcasted all over the network and then a device with corresponding routing rules takes over and processes them?

I am of course open for other routing solutions, so hit me up :)

**ii)**

Let's say I wanna use the mini-PC to handle all my traffic instead of an additional router. How good of an idea is this? Is there a security concern exposing those servers directly (even tho there is this default firewall on the server ofc)? Would I have to setup my mini-PC then in AP mode and connect all devices directly on it or will it be able to intercept the traffic somehow and then handle the packages correspondingly? If I setup my mini-PC in AP mode, I assume I would observe lesser network performance, as the mini-PC wifi card is not comparable to the one inside the router, right?

**iii)**

I would also like to monitor my network and have an overview of the traffic analytics. This question relates to the **ii)**, but I was generally wondering does this work on the interception principle or does the traffic have to flow through the device or maybe even both is possible? Have you got a suggestion regarding this (e.g. something with a mediocre dashboard and analytics - since I'm gonna be hosting a web server anyway)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Regarding port forwarding I came across this piece of software called ngrok, which enables me to do exactly the thing I want. My only concern is that it uses their external DNS servers in order to bypass NAT and resolve the routing

It uses their external *relay* servers. DNS alone is never enough to punch through NATs or firewalls. (The Ngrok relay servers do make use of DNS for HTTP virtual-hosting purposes, though.)

Specifically, the program works by making an *outbound* connection to an Ngrok relay host, keeping it idle but alive the whole time, and piggy-backing (tunneling) incoming requests over that connection. From your router's perspective, there weren't any inbound connections at all, just a very long outbound one.

> and if this could lead to security issues?

The connection only leads to Ngrok software (agent) running on your machine, so the only potential issues would come from vulnerabilities within the agent (e.g. problems in the way it parses the received HTTP requests). The agent is written in Golang, where such vulnerabilities are much less likely than e.g. an equivalent written in C.

Ngrok does relay all traffic through their servers, however, so you need to consider whether you're comfortable with that.

> I would rather have everything locally, if possible. I was also reading about the port forwarding using iptables:
> [...]
> I am just not sure how the traffic is handled? Does my mini-PC need to be ethernet connected to modem in order to work or do these packages get broadcasted all over the network and then a device with corresponding routing rules takes over and processes them?

Neither, really. The server cannot "pull" traffic to itself through a router, and packets are *never* broadcast across the entire LAN as you describe.

Such port-forwarding rules need to be set up **on the external router** – the one that currently has your "public" IP address. In most cases that'll be your modem, with its web-based control panel offering a "port forwarding" or "virtual server" option.

The iptables DNAT example isn't meant to be used on an ordinary server; rather, it is meant for people who use a Linux-based PC *as their home router* (meaning it is already in position to receive the traffic), so their purpose isn't to "pull" packets into the system but to handle already-received packets.

Ethernet vs Wi-Fi makes no difference here; IP behaves the same way regardless of the underlying transport.

(Of course, Ethernet would be much preferred for a server for *other* reasons, in particular because it's a dedicated full-duplex link, whereas bouncing from one Wi-Fi link to another will massively degrade performance. But that's entirely unrelated to how IP and packets behave.)

> Let's say I wanna use the mini-PC to handle all my traffic instead of an additional router. How good of an idea is this?

Mainly depends on how comfortable you are with whatever OS you're planning to use for that (are you going to use raw Linux? OpnSense? OpenWRT?), and whether the mini-PC physically has enough Ethernet interfaces (two would be better – if you only have one, you'll need a VLAN-capable Ethernet switch to multiplex both networks over that one port).

(Full-size PCs can easily have additional Ethernet ports installed in the form of PCI-Express cards; for a mini-PC you'd have to settle with USB, which is acceptable at best but not ideal.)

> Is there a security concern exposing those servers directly (even tho there is this default firewall on the server ofc)? Would I have to setup my mini-PC then in AP mode and connect all devices directly on it or will it be able to intercept the traffic somehow and then handle the packages correspondingly?

I'm really not sure what you mean here.

When comparing a server that's already "exposed" through e.g. a modem's port-forwarding, there is no difference. As long as others can make connections to a TCP port and talk to a service, they can make connections to a TCP port and talk to a service; neither a router nor a modem will somehow reject "malicious" packets through a connection which they have already allowed.

When comparing a server that's "exposed" via Ngrok, there is also very little difference, unless you use Ngrok's authentication features. While a proxy such as Ngrok *could* have security rules to block certain known-bad HTTP requests (some CDNs offer such a feature), I'm not sure whether they even offer this for their free tier at all.

> Would I have to setup my mini-PC then in AP mode and connect all devices directly on it or will it be able to intercept the traffic somehow and then handle the packages correspondingly?

Devices (neither servers nor routers) cannot "pull" or "intercept" traffic like that. If you want the mini-PC to become a router, it needs to be manually placed in the path (e.g. connecting modem→miniPC→LAN).

Keep in mind that being a Wi-Fi AP ("AP mode") is a *completely separate* task from being a router for IP packets. The mini-PC can be an AP without being a router (then it doesn't have any special requirements for how it's connected), and it can be a router without being an AP.

(Generally it can make a very good router but a poor AP, anyway.)

> If I setup my mini-PC in AP mode, I assume I would observe lesser network performance, as the mini-PC wifi card is not comparable to the one inside the router, right?

For Wi-Fi, often yes, even though the mini-PC might be capable of AP mode it likely will not be optimized for that. (For example, the multiple antennas on a dedicated AP aren't there for no reason – they work together for features such as beamforming.)

Again, being an AP for Wi-Fi is a completely separate task from being a router for IP traffic. You could use the mini-PC as purely an IP router *without* any Wi-Fi, then connect it via Ethernet to one or more dedicated Wi-Fi APs (either "enterprise" APs, or just regular wireless routers in AP mode).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145601/discussion-on-answer-by-user1686-home-network-traffic-monitoring-and-routing-sol); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.